# WPF XAML Islands - Using MediaCapture and VideoEffectDefinition

Tags: wpf, uwp, mediacapture, xaml-islands

Trying to create a WPF app, using UWP MediaCapture and a custom VideoEffect.

The VideoEffect is defined inside a Windows Runtime Component.

When adding the effect to MediaCapture, the app crashes with "Cannot find specified module. Failed to activate video effect"

Inside a new empty UWP app, the video effect works fine using the same code.

Comment: did you found a solution?